# Vuetify: Color data-table rows that pass check

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I have a datatable, in which there is valid tasks and non-valid tasks. I have the table working otherwise just fine, but issue is that I want to color rows that are non-valid as red so that users will know to fix them (no, fixing them on my end does not work).

I had read that item-class prop would work, however it does not seem to work in my case?

Here is the data-table setup:

```
<v-data-table
  disable-pagination
  hide-default-footer
  :headers="headers"
  :items="tasks"
  :hide-default-header="tasks == 0"
  :item-class="getRowClass"
>
```

In methods:

```
getRowClass(val) {
  if(val.in_use && !this.isTaskValid(val)){
    return 'invalid-row';
  }
},
```

In styles:

```
.invalid-row {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

If I use console.log to test out, I can see that getRowClass correctly identifies when the task is valid and when not, so it will enter correct if statement. However, I still do not see any rows colored red. I have read that other alternative is to replace entire section if `<tr>` and `<td>` tags, but I feel that kinda breaks the whole idea of using vuetify, especially since I need to specify each column separately now.

EDIT

I am using Vuetify 2.6.12 and Vue 2.6.14

Comment: In my opinion it looks good. Are you sure, that your conditon is correct? 'if(val.in_use && !this.isTaskValid(val))'. Maybe try to run your code without this condition. Just to see.

Comment: Yes. I have checked it. Using console.log to print out tasks that fail the test inside the if, before return, I can see it that selects the correct lines, but it still doesn't print them

Comment: which vuetify version are you using?

Comment: I added version numbers for both Vue and Vuetify into my question. Vuetify 2.6.12 and Vue 2.6.14

Comment: Is there maybe only a problem with your styles? Is the class "invalid-row" rendered into the html?

Comment: Is your style scoped?

Comment: @BeSter Development Yes, if I look into the HTML, I can see two ´<tr>´ with class `invalid-row`, so class is being applied. Altough, when I check it's inherited styles, I can not find `invalid-row` in it, which is strange...

Comment: @MarioSantini Yes, it is

Comment: Ok, than this is just a styling error. Did you defined your class on the right place?

Comment: @BeSterDevelopment Yes, it is defined in the same component as we construct our list and call the function. Style is scoped.

Comment: And the background-color attribute is not overwritten by another class or style-definition either?

Comment: @BeSterDevelopment As far as I can see, no. When I filter for `background-color` in the `<tr>` element, it shows no results, and manually looking through the inherited values there is no `background-color` that is being overridden. I can not find any overwriting in the td or div elements either inside tr

Comment: Thats very strange. Maybe try to define your class in a global accessable stylesheet.
Or try to use a default vuetify class like 'error' instead of your "invalid-row".

Comment: can you add your API result?

Comment: @ArslanButt What do you mean with API results? The dataset that I am using in tasks?

Comment: yes that's exactly

Comment: @ArslanButt Sorry, but that is not viable at the moment.

Comment: @BeSterDevelopment Interesting, when I replaced `invalid-row` class with `red darken-4`, it worked. That would indicate that custom style is not being loaded properly. I guess I need to go bug the guy in charge of styles :P

Comment: Check I add some code, as per your question this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
You need something like this
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Task',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Valid/not valid', value: 'isValid' },
      
      ],
      tasks: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'This is task 1',
          isValid: false,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'This is task 2',
          isValid: true,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'This is task 3',
          isValid: false,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'This is task 4',
          isValid: true,
        },

      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
     getRowClass(item) {
      if(item.isValid== false){
        return 'red'
      } 
    },
  },
})
```

```css
.invalid-row {
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="tasks"
      class="elevation-1"
      :item-class="getRowClass"            
    >
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```